# How to identify the GPS Mode currently in use in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, gps, navigation

I am developing a WP7 application wherein I need to check whether the GPS mode in use is either Full GPS or A-GPS.

I am unable to find any API that can provide me with this input. Few days back, I downloaded a app named GPSInfo from the marketplace and came to know that the app was displaying the current GPS mode in use. Is there any API that gives me the GPS mode's information?

Please guide.

Regards,

Tushar.

Answer (score 1):

If location detected by `GPS`, `VerticalAccuracy` will be not a `NAN`, so you can check by this property

Answer (score 1):

as I understand it, `GeoPositionAccuracy.High` translates into using GPS, whilst `GeoPositionAccuracy.Default` translates into use whatever means available (so it may be a cached GPS position, or it could be related to nearby WiFi spots, or even the mast that your phone is currently using).

It is worth noting that it is only possible to triangulate the position above sea level by using four (or more) satellites, so whilst presence of VerticalAccuracy indicates use of GPS, lack of does not indicate that you're not (it is still possible to get a 2D fix with 3 satellites)